# How to tell the subject under test to use the mock instead of its own variable

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to test a `LoginPresenter`, and I am using Mockito for the mocks.
Mockito doesnt let me `verify` a method invocation on the SUT so I have to mock its dependencies and `verify` their methods have been called by the `LoginPresenter`.

I got to the following situation:

LoginPresenter has a method called `attemptLogin`:

```
private void attemptLogin(String username, String password) {
    new LoginNetworkOperation(username, password).execute();
}
```

I have to mock `LoginNetworkOperation` and using Mockito, `verify` the method invocation on `execute()`.

```
@Test
public void testWhenUserNameAndPasswordAreEnteredShouldAttemptLogin() throws Exception {
    LoginView loginView = Mockito.mock(LoginView.class);
    LoginNetworkOperation loginNetworkOperation = Mockito.mock(LoginNetworkOperation.class);
    Mockito.when(loginView.getUserName()).thenReturn("George");
    Mockito.when(loginView.getPassword()).thenReturn("aaaaaa");
    loginPresenter.setLoginView(loginView);
    loginPresenter.onLoginClicked();
    Mockito.verify(loginNetworkOperation.execute());
}
```

However, how do I make `LoginPresenter` use the mocked LoginNetworkOperation instead of the one it creates in the `attemptLogin` method? I need to change the design of LoginPresenter to use a member variable, and provide a setter for it, which is suboptimal because a local variable in the method is plenty, as it is used only there.

Am I going about this whole thing wrong?

Initially, I wanted to verify that `LoginPresenter`'s `attemptLogin` is called, but Mockito can only verify mocked objects' methods and I cannot spy on `LoginPresenter` because it is final (generated by `AndroidAnnotations`)

Comment: You might have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585490/androidannotations-and-unit-testing#10621419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w

The biggest takeaway is: **don't mix object creation logic with business logic**
which means don't instantiate objects in methods or constructors (probably use DI instead), because the test code has no power over what chain-reaction starts whenever a SUT's constructor or a method is called, that is bound to a `new` keyword.

That means that in my case, the `LoginPresenter` shouldn't be responsible for creating the `LoginNetworkOperation` object but should take it from the outside

That way I will be able to tell it to use the mock instead of the concrete implementation, and thus, I will be able to do my tests